# Pandas - Vectorizing/Improving efficiency of function without iterrtuples()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Currently this is my function and I'm wondering if there's a way to vectorize/improve the efficiency of it without having to iterate through the DataFrame with itertuples()? Currently it's not that slow but there are over 250000 rows.

```
def function(dataframe, *actions):
    sources_list = []   
    for dict_row in dataframe.itertuples(index=False):
        for entry in dict_row:
            temp_json_data = json.loads(entry)
            for dict_entry in temp_json_data:
                if dict_entry['action'] in actions:
                    sources_list.append(dict_entry)
    return sources_list
```

Basically what this function is trying to achieve is that it goes through each row in the DataFrame, dict_row becomes a Pandas object and each entry item is a string. We convert each entry string to a dictionary with json.loads() and try to see if the new created dictionaries contain a key that's part of the *actions argument list, if so we append it to a list.

Here's a representative dataset:

```
    actions
0   [{"E": 24, "action": "views"}, {"F": 22, "action": "noise"}, {"H": 39, "action": "conversions"}]
1   [{"B": 79, "action": "clicks"}, {"H": 3, "action": "conversions"}, {"G": 68, "action": "junk"}]
2   [{"E": 10, "action": "views"}, {"D": 41, "action": "views"}, {"J": 52, "action": "conversions"}]
3   [{"A": 47, "action": "clicks"}, {"E": 93, "action": "junk"}, {"D": 54, "action": "views"}]
4   [{"H": 16, "action": "views"}, {"G": 41, "action": "conversions"}, {"C": 80, "action": "junk"}]
5   [{"J": 57, "action": "noise"}, {"E": 93, "action": "views"}, {"H": 20, "action": "conversions"}]
6   [{"F": 5, "action": "junk"}, {"A": 11, "action": "junk"}, {"G": 98, "action": "junk"}]
7   [{"C": 36, "action": "junk"}, {"G": 38, "action": "clicks"}, {"D": 71, "action": "junk"}]
8   [{"A": 22, "action": "noise"}, {"C": 9, "action": "clicks"}, {"E": 94, "action": "conversions"}]
9   [{"E": 64, "action": "clicks"}, {"J": 80, "action": "junk"}, {"E": 77, "action": "conversions"}]
```

which can be recreated with the following snippet:

```
data = [["[{\"E\": 24, \"action\": \"views\"},  {\"F\": 22, \"action\": \"noise\"},       {\"H\": 39, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"],
        ["[{\"B\": 79, \"action\": \"clicks\"}, {\"H\": 3,  \"action\": \"conversions\"}, {\"G\": 68, \"action\": \"junk\"       }]"],
        ["[{\"E\": 10, \"action\": \"views\"},  {\"D\": 41, \"action\": \"views\"},       {\"J\": 52, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"],
        ["[{\"A\": 47, \"action\": \"clicks\"}, {\"E\": 93, \"action\": \"junk\"},        {\"D\": 54, \"action\": \"views\"      }]"],
        ["[{\"H\": 16, \"action\": \"views\"},  {\"G\": 41, \"action\": \"conversions\"}, {\"C\": 80, \"action\": \"junk\"       }]"],
        ["[{\"J\": 57, \"action\": \"noise\"},  {\"E\": 93, \"action\": \"views\"},       {\"H\": 20, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"],
        ["[{\"F\": 5,  \"action\": \"junk\"},   {\"A\": 11, \"action\": \"junk\"},        {\"G\": 98, \"action\": \"junk\"       }]"],
        ["[{\"C\": 36, \"action\": \"junk\"},   {\"G\": 38, \"action\": \"clicks\"},      {\"D\": 71, \"action\": \"junk\"       }]"],
        ["[{\"A\": 22, \"action\": \"noise\"},  {\"C\": 9,  \"action\": \"clicks\"},      {\"E\": 94, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"],
        ["[{\"E\": 64, \"action\": \"clicks\"}, {\"J\": 80, \"action\": \"junk\"},        {\"E\": 77, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['actions'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is not great for storing and manipulating iterables as values. You could get better performance by restructuring the data *before* it goes into the DataFrame.

That said, not all is lost. You can employ multiprocessing to parallelize the task by breaking the DataFrame into chunks.

```
import json
import multiprocessing
from itertools import chain

import pandas as pd

def function(dataframe, *actions):
    sources_list = []
    for dict_row in dataframe.itertuples(index=False):
        for entry in dict_row:
            temp_json_data = json.loads(entry)
            for dict_entry in temp_json_data:
                if dict_entry['action'] in actions:
                    sources_list.append(dict_entry)
    return sources_list


class Parser:

    def __init__(self, dataframe, *actions):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.actions = actions

    def helper(self, idx0, idxf):
        result = []
        for datapoint in chain(*self.dataframe.loc[idx0:idxf, 'actions'].apply(json.loads)):
            if datapoint['action'] in self.actions:
                result.append(datapoint)
        return result

    def run(self, P=1):
        N = self.dataframe.shape[0]
        if P > 1:
            with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=P) as pool:
                n = N // P
                results = pool.starmap(self.helper, ([n*i, min(n*(i+1)-1, N)] for i in range(P)))
        else:
            results = [self.helper(0, N)]
        return list(chain(*results))

data = [["[{\"E\": 24, \"action\": \"views\"},  {\"F\": 22, \"action\": \"noise\"},       {\"H\": 39, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"],
        ["[{\"B\": 79, \"action\": \"clicks\"}, {\"H\": 3,  \"action\": \"conversions\"}, {\"G\": 68, \"action\": \"junk\"       }]"],
        ["[{\"E\": 10, \"action\": \"views\"},  {\"D\": 41, \"action\": \"views\"},       {\"J\": 52, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"],
        ["[{\"A\": 47, \"action\": \"clicks\"}, {\"E\": 93, \"action\": \"junk\"},        {\"D\": 54, \"action\": \"views\"      }]"],
        ["[{\"H\": 16, \"action\": \"views\"},  {\"G\": 41, \"action\": \"conversions\"}, {\"C\": 80, \"action\": \"junk\"       }]"],
        ["[{\"J\": 57, \"action\": \"noise\"},  {\"E\": 93, \"action\": \"views\"},       {\"H\": 20, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"],
        ["[{\"F\": 5,  \"action\": \"junk\"},   {\"A\": 11, \"action\": \"junk\"},        {\"G\": 98, \"action\": \"junk\"       }]"],
        ["[{\"C\": 36, \"action\": \"junk\"},   {\"G\": 38, \"action\": \"clicks\"},      {\"D\": 71, \"action\": \"junk\"       }]"],
        ["[{\"A\": 22, \"action\": \"noise\"},  {\"C\": 9,  \"action\": \"clicks\"},      {\"E\": 94, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"],
        ["[{\"E\": 64, \"action\": \"clicks\"}, {\"J\": 80, \"action\": \"junk\"},        {\"E\": 77, \"action\": \"conversions\"}]"]]

actions = ['views', 'clicks', 'conversions']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data*25000, columns=['actions'])
```

Note that I have attempted to emulate your 250000 row dataset by duplicating your example 10 row dataset by 25000x. (If you try to employ multiprocessing on small datasets, it will probably perform worse. Benefits are only gained at scale.)

Using just a single process, this method is slightly faster.

```
In [2]: %timeit function(df, *actions)
2.41 s ± 10.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit Parser(df, *actions).run(P=1)
2.1 s ± 3.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Depending on your CPU, you may be able to reduce the runtime by 100% or more. If you have too many processes though, you will saturate your hardware as can be seen below.

```
In [4]: %timeit Parser(df, *actions).run(P=2)
1.67 s ± 6.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [5]: %timeit Parser(df, *actions).run(P=4)
1.04 s ± 33.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [6]: %timeit Parser(df, *actions).run(P=8)
1.06 s ± 23.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [7]: %timeit Parser(df, *actions).run(P=16)
1.11 s ± 37.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [8]: %timeit Parser(df, *actions).run(P=32)
1.34 s ± 38.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for the answer but some reason I can't get the Parser class to run faster than the iterative approach even with increasing the processes. The smallest gap I've had was 2.375264015999619 s (Parser with p=4) 1.8327569220000441 s (Function). I didn't use %timeit but I had a start and endtime inside the function calls with the timeit.default_timer module.

Comment: @animusdx. Gah. I'm sure neither of us are "wrong" about our numbers. It might just be a difference in hardware. (For reference, mine is an older, low-end laptop with 4 cores.) Sorry my answer wasn't more helpful.